# Does using jQuery.get effectively double the ping time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have some script myScript.js that uses jQuery.get() to retrieve a small piece of data from the server.  Suppose also that my ping time is horrible at 1500ms.  Does using jQuery.get effectively double the ping time to 3000ms?

Or is there async magic that allows some sort of parallel processing?  The reason I'm asking is that we use jQuery.get() fairly liberally and I'm wondering if it is an area we need to look at optimizing.

Edit: double compared to if I can somehow rearrange things to just load all the data upon the initial load and bypass jQuery get altogether

Comment: I don't know, but have a look at the developer tools - the network section in it specifically. If you see any difference (I don't see why you would see any difference) in timings, you'll have the answer.

Comment: If you're saying you load a page and then do a jQuery.get(), then yes, the 'ping' is doubled.

Comment: yes, it will be better to bootstrap the needed data at the beginning if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Ping time is usually server-related, where as jQuery is all client side. So the answer is no, it doesn't affect your ping time.

If you're asking if using jQuery.get (or ajax in general) can make your client side slower then the answer is that yes, the more JS you have then generally the slower the client gets if you're trying to process a lot of things since everything pretty much runs on the same thread. However, by default these ajax requests are asynchronous so until the server sends the response back the thread is usually idling anyways.

I'd suggest you open your page in Chrome and use the developer tools to see the network usage. That will tell you exactly how much time is taken 'waiting' on the server.

Comment: I don't think he's referring to the actual latency.  It sounds to me like he's asking about system response to the latency.

Answer (score 0):

If you break down a request, you can get an idea of what latency you can expect.

Every TCP connection begins with a [three-way-handshake](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml):

- SYN (client to server)
- SYN-ACK (server to client)
- ACK (client to server)

If the request fits in the size of one tcp packet (~1500 bytes) it can be sent as the last part of the handshake to optimize the network flow.

The response might be sent in just one packet as well (depending on its size). Once sent, both sides engage in a connection termination which takes two pairs of FIN-ACK sequences unless the connection is kept alive. At this point I'm not entirely sure whether the server can send FIN together with the last response packet.

So, in the best case scenario you can expect at least 2x ping time, but more likely 3-4x.